# Is there a word for it?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I would like to use a word or phrase to describe a situation where one has a goal in mind and  access to all the resources(Connections, Money, Knowledge) but isn't working hard to achieve its goals. Therefore he should be feeling guilty.

Is there any word to describe that "guiltiness"?

One Usage of the would in the sentence would be like " I am feeling xxx, I need to start working towards my goal"

Thanks.

Comment: Lazy? <Filler characters. To Stack Exachange admins: I am a Trusted User, for God's sake; why do I need filler characters?>

Comment: **Unproductive.**  If he's a writer, you'd say he **has writer's block**.  If he's an artist, he's feeling **uninspired**. But neither of these necessarily entail guilt. But as I see it, guilt is always optional.

Comment: Thanks @brian , sometimes when I am looking for words to describe something, I tend to omit the obvious :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the exact answers; however I suggest the followings:

1. [*laziness*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/laziness)

> an inclination not to do work or engage in activities.

Also, it's [defined](http://www.successconsciousness.com/overcoming-laziness.htm) as:

> It is the desire to be idle, to do nothing and resist effort.

**E.g.**

> although she often talks about ambitious household projects, nothing even gets started because of her chronic laziness.

2. [*Underaceiver*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underachiever)

> An underachiever is a person and especially a student who fails to achieve his or her potential or does not do as well as expected. The term is also used more generally, for example a sports team that **contains many star players** but still **loses games** against teams with relatively little obvious talent would be termed underachieving.

Answer (score 1):

They are **slothful**.

> **[Sloth](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sloth)** - Reluctance to work or make an effort; laziness

as for "guiltiness" do you mean **shame**? and technically you can call the situation "a shame" as well.

> **Shame** - Distress or embarrassment at having failed or been humiliated